# Json String that doesn't want to be deserialized

Tags: c#, json

I am stuck on a json deserialization, it seems that there's something I can't catch on this json :

```
{
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "result" : [{
            "Currency" : "DOGE",
            "Balance" : 0.00000000,
            "Available" : 0.00000000,
            "Pending" : 0.00000000,
            "CryptoAddress" : "DLxcEt3AatMyr2NTatzjsfHNoB9NT62HiF",
            "Requested" : false,
            "Uuid" : null

        }, {
            "Currency" : "BTC",
            "Balance" : 14.21549076,
            "Available" : 14.21549076,
            "Pending" : 0.00000000,
            "CryptoAddress" : "1Mrcdr6715hjda34pdXuLqXcju6qgwHA31",
            "Requested" : false,
            "Uuid" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code I am trying :

```
       if (stream == null) return account;
        var re = new StreamReader(stream);
        var json = re.ReadToEnd();
        var jobj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        var items = jobj.Children()
            .Cast<JProperty>()
            .Select(j => new
            {
                ID = j.Name,
                Other = (string)j.Value["Currency"]
            })
            .ToList();
```

But unfortunately, nothing happens with this code, and I'm quite stuck as to why. After searching around here, and trying several other solutions found on similar thread, this one is the closest I could get to deseraliaze my string.

I have two class I wish to fill in with this json :

```
public class AccountCurrencies
{
    public string Jsonid { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public double Available { get; set; }
    public double Pending { get; set; }
    public string CryptoAddress { get; set; }
    public bool Requested { get; set; }
    public object Uuid { get; set; }
}

public class AccountWrapper
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<AccountCurrencies> AccountAllCurrencies  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you just used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountWrapper>(json)`?  Just add the appropriate properties like 'result' to AccountWrapper and it should all wire up.

Comment: It was indeed the solution. I'm going to go back through any documentation I can find in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two things here. Firstly to get the Json into your class structure is a single line of code:

```
var yourObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountWrapper>(json);
```

Secondly, you need to tell the serialiser the the `AccountAllCurrencies` property is called "result" in the Json data. To do this, use the `JsonProperty` attribute:

```
public class AccountWrapper
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    //Add this line
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public List<AccountCurrencies> AccountAllCurrencies  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. I'll check to see if there's some kind of documentation about this nuget package somewhere. Thank you for the answer.